# POWERSHELL script add-content in task scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Here is my script :

```
# Fichier de sortie
$OutFile = "xxx.csv"
remove-item $OutFile
ADD-content -path $OutFile -value "POSTE;UPTIME;NBRE DE JOURS UP;"

# Chercher les postes...
foreach ($poste in Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=xx,DC=xxxx,DC=COM" )
    {
    # ... et voir ceux qui sont inaccessbles
    ping -n 1 $poste.name
    if ( $? -eq $false ) 
        {
        write-host ('test')
        }
    else
        { 
        $LastBootUpTime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Comp $poste.name | Select -Exp LastBootUpTime
        $uptime = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($LastBootUpTime)
        $now = get-date
        $span = New-TimeSpan -start $uptime -end $now
        $result = "$($poste.name);$uptime;$($span.days)"
        ADD-content -path $OutFile -value $result
        }
    }
```

This script is ok when i launch it in powershell. Line sample :

```
COMP_NAME;03/10/2022 08:31:07;0
```

But when i launch it via task scheduler, line sample :

```
COMP_NAME;;
```

two variables are not wrote.
Can you help me?
Regards.

Comment: Does the service account running the scheduled task have permissions to query the computers?

Comment: This is "system" account of a member server of the domain.

Comment: By "System" do you mean `NT AUTHORITY\System` ?

Comment: Yes. i have changed with a domain admin account and it works well.  i need user which is local admin for all computers. thanks a lot.